# Are AsyncTasks also executed on the same background thread in the SERIAL_EXECUTOR?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, threadpoolexecutor

Question about the Order of Execution of `AsyncTasks` on Honeycomb+. Per [Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.

My question is, will the AsyncTasks that are being executed serially in the background also be run on the same thread?

For example, will the [`AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR) that is executing tasks A, B, and C, run task A on thread 1, then task B on thread 1, then task C on thread 1?

Or, is it possible that the `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR` will execute task A on thread 1, then task B on thread 2, then task C on on thread 3? In this scheme, all the tasks ARE executed serially, but they are being run on different background threads.

I ask because I added some debugging code to my doInBackground and I am seeing threads named `AsyncTask #5`, `AsyncTask #4`, `AsyncTask #2`, and `AsyncTask #3`, when I assumed I would just see a single thread every time named "AsyncTask Worker" or something.

(I just want to confirm my own mental model of how AsyncTasks are expected to work; I am not reporting a bug or problem in this question.)

Thanks!

Comment: "will the AsyncTasks that are being executed serially in the background also be run on the same thread?" -- [the implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) is rather odd. Rather than use a single-thread thread pool, `AsyncTask` maintains its own queue, and feeds tasks to the regular multiple-thread thread pool (the one visible as `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`) one at a time. Hence, your observed behavior is eminently reasonable.

Comment: Thank you! If you would like to post this as an answer for me to accept I am happy to do so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will the AsyncTasks that are being executed serially in the background also be run on the same thread?

[The implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) is rather odd. Rather than use a single-thread thread pool, AsyncTask maintains its own queue, and feeds tasks to the regular multiple-thread thread pool (the one visible as THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) one at a time.

> is it possible that the AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR will execute task A on thread 1, then task B on thread 2, then task C on on thread 3? In this scheme, all the tasks ARE executed serially, but they are being run on different background threads.

That's very possible, assuming that `ThreadPoolExecutor` does not always hand out the same thread if the pool is presently unused. That's getting deeper into Android's implementation of Java framework classes than I usually go. Also note that the implementation of `ThreadPoolExecutor` itself will change in the future, as Android is moving to the OpenJDK and away from their Apache Harmony-based framework classes. Hence, I'd try not to make any assumptions about how the implementation of `ThreadPoolExecutor` will work.